# Deleting sheets that have yet to be made from a spreadsheet through Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

The program that I have posted is already working which does the following :

1. **newOpex(), newMBAP(), and newCashDR()** are functions that create a copy of their respective sheets which are copied from a template sheet named **templateOpex, templateMBAP, and templateCashDR** which is within the spreadsheet. The template sheet is basically an empty form of the sheet of each which is **RCDisb (OpEx) : Current**, **RCDisb (MBAP) : Current**, and **CashDR : Current**. When any of the 3 functions is called, It changes the name of the sheet to its respective number **( Ex.from RCDisb (OpEx) : Current to RCDisb (OpEx) : Sheet #1 )** and changes the newly made sheet to **Current**.
2. When the function **resetSCA()** is called, it copies the spreadsheet into a folder in Google Drive and deletes the sheets inside the Spreadsheet and reproduces a fresh copy of **templateOpex, templateMBAP, and templateCashDR** ready to be used by the user again.

Now my issue is that, I can't seem to find a way to delete the sheets including the ones that were just added without it touching the **DV Logbook** and the other **Template sheets** and without the code failing due to **null** which is caused by the newly added sheets.

```
const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const ws_lb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DV Logbook");
const ws_opex = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("RCDisb (OpEx) : Current");
const ws_mbap = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("RCDisb (MBAP) : Current");
const ws_cashdr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CashDR : Current");

//lastrow_indicators
const lastrow_lb = ws_lb.getLastRow();
const lastrow_opex = ws_opex.getLastRow();
const lastrow_mbap = ws_mbap.getLastRow();
const lastrow_cashdr = ws_cashdr.getLastRow();

function newOpex(){
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var rcdisbopex = 1;
var result = ui.prompt(
      ' Create New Operating Expense Sheet',
      'Please enter Sheet Number:',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Process the user's response.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText()
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
  var newOpexName = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("RCDisb (OpEx) : Current").setName("RCDisb (OpEx) : Sheet #"+ rcdisbopex);
  var newOpexSheet = newOpexName.getSheetName();
  Logger.log(newOpexSheet);
  rcdisbopex++;
  var templateSheet = SpreadsheetApp .getSheetByName('templateOpEx');
  ws.insertSheet('RCDisb (OpEx) : Current', 2, {template: templateSheet});
  var sheetName = ('RCDisb (OpEx) : Current');
  Logger.log(sheetName);
  Utilities.sleep(1000)

  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    // User clicked "Cancel".
    ui.alert('⚠️Operation Cancelled.');
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // User clicked X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('⚠️You closed the dialog.');
  }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  ss.getRange(9, 8, 1, 1).setValue(text)
  ss.getRange(8, 8, 1, 1).setValue(text)
  ss.getRange(5, 6, 1, 1).setValue("Period Covered: "+ date)
}

function newMBAP(){
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var rcdisbmbap = 1;
var result = ui.prompt(
      ' Create New Medical and Burial Assistance Sheet',
      'Please enter Sheet Number:',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Process the user's response.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText()
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
  var newMBAPName = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("RCDisb (MBAP) : Current").setName("RCDisb (MBAP) : Sheet #"+ rcdisbmbap);
  var newMBAPSheet = newMBAPName.getSheetName();
  Logger.log(newMBAPSheet);
  rcdisbmbap++;
  var templateSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('templateMBAP');
  ws.insertSheet('RCDisb (MBAP) : Current', 4, {template: templateSheet});
  var sheetName = ('RCDisb (MBAP) : Current');
  Logger.log(sheetName);
  Utilities.sleep(1000)

  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    // User clicked "Cancel".
    ui.alert('⚠️Operation Cancelled.');
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // User clicked X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('⚠️You closed the dialog.');
  }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  ss.getRange(9, 8, 1, 1).setValue(text)
  ss.getRange(8, 8, 1, 1).setValue(text)
  ss.getRange(5, 6, 1, 1).setValue("Period Covered: "+ date)
}

function newCashDR(){
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var cashdrNum = 1;
var result = ui.prompt(
      ' Create New Cash Disbursements Record Sheet',
      'Please enter Sheet Number:',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Process the user's response.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText()
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
  var newCashDRName = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("CashDR : Current").setName("CashDR : Sheet #"+ cashdrNum);
  var newCashDRSheet = newCashDRName.getSheetName();
  Logger.log(newCashDRSheet);
  cashdrNum++;
  var templateSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('templateCashDR');
  ws.insertSheet('CashDR : Current', 6, {template: templateSheet});
  var sheetName = ('CashDR : Current');
  Logger.log(sheetName);
  Utilities.sleep(1000)

  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    // User clicked "Cancel".
    ui.alert('⚠️Operation Cancelled.');
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // User clicked X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('⚠️You closed the dialog.');
  }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  ss.getRange(8, 9, 1, 1).setValue(text)
}

function resetSCA(){
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("14NSBP1OFTPtY8xdV7IIo2m7GNRBAeJDQ"); 
  DriveApp.getFileById("1h3rg7rqmteYAnVFSAzIS-hr5bbnwgRFitIDhZp5javo").makeCopy(date + "_SCA_DavaoDisbursements", destFolder); 
  ws_lb.deleteRows(2, 100);
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  if (sheets[4] == sheets){
    ws.deleteSheet(sheets[4]);
  } else if (sheets[5] == sheets){
    ws.deleteSheet(sheets[5]);
  } else if (sheets[6] == sheets){
    ws.deleteSheet(sheets[6]);
  } else if (sheets[7] == sheets){
    ws.deleteSheet(sheets[7]);
  } else if (sheets[8] == sheets){
    ws.deleteSheet(sheets[8]);
  } else if (sheets[9] == sheets){
    ws.deleteSheet(sheets[9]);
  }

  var templateSheetopex = ws.getSheetByName('templateOpEx');
  var templateSheetmbap = ws.getSheetByName('templateMBAP');
  var templateSheetcashdr = ws.getSheetByName('templateCashDR');
  ws.insertSheet('RCDisb (OpEx) : Current', 2, {template: templateSheetopex});
  ws.insertSheet('RCDisb (MBAP) : Current', 3, {template: templateSheetmbap});
  ws.insertSheet('CashDR : Current', 4, {template: templateSheetcashdr});
}
```

I can't seem to really find a method that really fits the problem. I would especially be interested in methods that can simplify the process of the code.

Extra information about the code: the code uses Custom Menus and sub-menus while the input is placed through a Google Form.

[image]

I have reproduced a whole working sample of the code for your reference except for the resetSCA() as I can't reproduce a sample of the Google Drive for readers to see.

**Code sample:** https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z7N__RHwxK1Xp9YMUxA4sMq37U8TiCMiD39jTFP0Zxg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Now my issue is that, I cant seem to find a way to delete the sheets including the ones that were just added without it touching the DV Logbook and the other Template sheets and without the code failing due to null which is caused by the newly added sheets.` and `and if possibly I would've wanted to create sheets without it being stuck to #1 meaning it can possibly recreate more than 3 sheets of the same kind.`. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal?

Comment: My goal is to delete selected sheets in my spreadsheet which is RCDisb (OpEx) : Current, RCDisb (MBAP) : Current, and CashDR : Current including the ones that are yet to be generated by the functions newOpex(), newMBAP(), and newCashDR(). refer to the function resetSCA() to see the attempt on the if-statement

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. From your reply, you just want to delete multiple sheets by the sheet names. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, precisely what I want to happen. the tricky part for me are the sheets that have yet to be made.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the detail of `the tricky part for me are the sheets that have yet to be made.`? And, about your `resetSCA()`, what do you want to do below the line of `var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();`? `sheets` is an array. But it seems that in your script, this array is compared with Sheet object. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected result. But, I thought that this might be related to your expected result. So, can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: That is a trial in my part so any method that can be used to attain the goal would suffice and again you don't have to apologize for your English every time sir Tanaike as this has not been my first time in discussing with you. I will be patient enough to explain to you over and over again to fix my problem. cheers!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that my English skill hasn't improved. I apologize for this. About your goal, is your goal to complete your function `resetSCA()`? If my understanding is correct, when `resetSCA()` is run, can I ask you about the sample input and output situation you expect? From this information, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: resetSCA() basically copies and saves the spreadsheet in a folder in Google Drive while it deletes all the sheets inside the current spreadsheet including the newly created ones and then reproduces a fresh copy of the same sheets afterwards. in short its a reset spreadsheet button. The copying and saving is already done and working all I need is the deleting of sheets.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your expected result from your reply. For example, what do you want to delete sheets in the active Spreadsheet? Can I ask you about the sheet names you want to delete? And, what sheets do you want to copy to the active Spreadsheet? Can I ask you about the sheet names you want to copy?

Comment: i would want to delete RCDisb (OpEx) : Current, RCDisb (MBAP) : Current, CashDR : Current, and if already generated, RCDisb (OpEx) : Sheet #1, RCDisb (MBAP) : Sheet #1, CashDR : Sheet #1. The sheets to be copied are templateOpex, templateMBAP, templateCashDR which are also included in the active spreadsheet. hope this helps

Comment: From your reply, your showing script and your provided Spreadsheet, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result and that was not useful, I apologize again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- About the active Spreadsheet, you want to delete the sheets `RCDisb (OpEx) : Current, RCDisb (MBAP) : Current, CashDR : Current, and if already generated, RCDisb (OpEx) : Sheet #1, RCDisb (MBAP) : Sheet #1, CashDR : Sheet #1`.
- And, you want to copy the sheets `templateOpex, templateMBAP, templateCashDR`

  - From your showing script and your provided Spreadsheet, you want to rename the copied sheets from `templateOpex, templateMBAP, templateCashDR` to `RCDisb (OpEx) : Current, RCDisb (MBAP) : Current, CashDR : Current`, respectively. And, you want to set the sheets to the index of 1, 2, and 3.

If my understanding is correct, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function sample() {
  const deleteSheetNames = ["RCDisb (OpEx) : Current", "RCDisb (MBAP) : Current", "CashDR : Current", "RCDisb (OpEx) : Sheet #1", "RCDisb (MBAP) : Sheet #1", "CashDR : Sheet #1"];
  const copySheetNames = [{ copy: "templateOpex", name: "RCDisb (OpEx) : Current", index: 1 }, { copy: "templateMBAP", name: "RCDisb (MBAP) : Current", index: 2 }, { copy: "templateCashDR", name: "CashDR : Current", index: 3 }];

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Delete sheets.
  deleteSheetNames.forEach(name => {
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    if (!sheet) return;
    ss.deleteSheet(sheet);
  });

  // Copy sheets.
  copySheetNames.forEach(({ copy, name, index }) => {
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(copy);
    if (!sheet) return;
    ss.insertSheet(name, index, { template: sheet });
  });
}
```

- About your script `resetSCA()`, `sheets` of `var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();` is an array. But, in your script, Class Sheet object is compared with an array including Class Sheet objects at `sheets[4] == sheets`. I thought that this might be your current issue.
- When this script is run, I thought that the above goal is achieved.

#### Note:

- If you want to change the index of the copied sheet, please modify `copySheetNames`.
- If you are required to use the following script, please add it to top of the above function.

  ```
    var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("14NSBP1OFTPtY8xdV7IIo2m7GNRBAeJDQ"); 
    DriveApp.getFileById("1h3rg7rqmteYAnVFSAzIS-hr5bbnwgRFitIDhZp5javo").makeCopy(date + "_SCA_DavaoDisbursements", destFolder); 
    ws_lb.deleteRows(2, 100);
  ```

#### Reference:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: constantly amazed at how knowledgable and good you are at google apps script. Thanks sir Tanaike as usual! Wish you the best.

Comment: @Dean Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. By your cooperation, I could correctly understand your question. Thank you, too.